# JQuery nth-child not working properly

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I am using JQuery's nth-child selector to alter the margin on every 3rd div with a class of photo_post_thumbnail, but it alters it every 2nd div?

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

**Site**

http://www.clients.eirestudio.net/hatstand/wordpress/photos/

**HTML markup**

```
<div class="postbox photo_post_thumbnail">
      blah blah
</div>

<div class="postbox photo_post_thumbnail">
      blah blah
</div>

<div class="postbox photo_post_thumbnail">
      blah blah
</div>
```

**JQuery Code**

```
$('.photo_post_thumbnail:nth-child(3n)').css('margin-right', '0px');
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's doing this because you have a `<h1>` before those divs, making that div the 4th child not the third :)

The `nth-child` selector is a bit confusing at first because it's the `nth-child` **of the parent**, not just the `nth-child` *matching that selector* of the parent, the selector has no bearing the position for this selector.

To get the div you want, do `3n+1` like this:

```
$('.photo_post_thumbnail:nth-child(3n+1)').css('margin-right', '0px');
```

Comment: Yes totally agree on that :D +1

Comment: I am confused (after looking at his page), should this not be the nth instance within tags with that class?  Why would the sibling h1 matter? should he use :eq(n) instead?

Comment: I guess I need to research the nth child stuff some :) (duh, nth child of parent, not nth instance of the selected elements :) I should have read more first :)

Comment: @Mark - That's the confusing part I mentioned :) the `n` doesn't care about the class selector, `:nth-child` is it's *own* selector, just like `:last` or `:not()`, etc...so it's matching the fact that it's `class="photo_post_thumbnail"` **and** `:nth-child(3n+1)`, the `n` doesn't care about the class that's a different selector.  Before your div was the 3rd child **and** had that class, so it matched.  What you want is to match that class and every 3rd child + 1 offset for the `<h1>`, that make more sense?

Answer (score 5):

Alternative solution :

```
   $('.photo_post_thumbnail').each(function(i) {
      i=(i+1);
      if(i%3==0){
     $(this).css("margin-right","0px"));
    }
   });
```

Comment: I think you meant `$('.photo_post_thumbnail').each(function(i) {` here, the `$.each()` expects a collection as the first argument :)

Comment: Great - thanks. I still had issues with the (3n+1) solutions above, but your solution worked fine straight away.