# How to change color in class nth-child() in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, rangeslider

I want to make rating filter star using range slider jquery ui and set star color in class (.star-group) to red.
for example, if value rating 1, I want to set color red in ( .star-group:nth-child(5) )
here the code:

```
$( "#slider-range" ).slider({
  orientation: "vertical",
  range: true,
  min: 1,
    max: 5,
    values: [2,4],
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#amount" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] );
    for(i=1; i<=ui.values[0];i++) {
        //$(".df:nth-child("+i+")").addClass('clgray');
      $(".star-group").addClass('red');
    }
  }
});
$( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) + 
" - " + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
```

see more here: https://jsfiddle.net/equ92qn8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here for the tested solution with comments added:  https://jsfiddle.net/u3448okL/

I added a few comments in the code, to see what I did. Please ask if anything is unclear.

The correct code is:

```
$( "#slider-range" ).slider({
  orientation: "vertical",
  range: true,
  min: 1,
    max: 5,
    values: [2,4],
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#amount" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] ); 

    // Reset to previous colors (by removing .red class)
    $(".star-group").removeClass('red');

    // For each group of stars ...
    $(".star-group").each(function(){

        // ... check if the number of stars in this object is in the VALUES INTERVAL, then add class RED        
        if ($(this).find('i').length >= ui.values[0] && $(this).find('i').length <= ui.values[1]){
            $(this).addClass('red');
         }
     })
  }
});
$( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) + " - " + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
```

Please note that I avoided using nth-child() because of "safety". We could have done it with it, but in my opinion it was safer the way above.

Please read here why nth-child can be tricky: [JQuery nth-child not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699096/jquery-nth-child-not-working-properly)

Comment: thank you very much... you are my hero today.. and thanks for the note.  :)